# Browser Extension - How do I stop autofocus from going to the address bar?

Tags: html, forms, google-chrome-extension, autofocus

I have a browser extension which replaces the new tab page with a page that has a nice background and a search bar. Using the search bar takes the user to google and searches for the query (in the same tab). For some reason, when using the extension version, the autofocus doesn't go into my search form and instead goes into the address bar. I can't for the life of me figure out why. Did I muck this up someplace? This is my search form:

```
<html>

<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Search</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="popup.css" />
</head>

<body>

<div id="searchContainer">
<form action="http://google.ca/search" method="GET" >
<input id="field" type="search" name="q" size="20" placeholder="Google Search" autofocus />&nbsp;
<input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Search" />
</form>
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Thank you!

Comment: I think this is something that's hard-coded in Chrome/Chromium...

Comment: Like extensions aren't allowed to autofocus and it defaults to the address bar?

Comment: Yes, but only in the new-tab-page.

Comment: Yeah you appear to be right. Opening a new tab goes puts the focus into the address bar by browser default and there doesn't seem to be a way around it. The only way autofocus works in a new tab is to open the new tab, click into the page, and refresh. *sigh* ... I'm thinking maybe I can do something in the manifest file, but I'm runnin low on hope.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is hard-coded in Chrome to match behavior of the built-in newtab.

It can't be changed but an [official workaround](https://crbug.com/1085779#c26) is to **redirect via `location` to another URL**. The address bar will show a full chrome-extension:// URL though.

**manifest.json**:

```js
"chrome_url_overrides": {
  "newtab": "focus.html"
},
```

**focus.html**:

```html
<script src=focus.js></script>
```

**focus.js**:

```js
location = 'start-focused.html';
```

**start-focused.html** will have the actual contents of your newtab UI.

Comment: This seems to work and focusses on the field when I open a new tab, however it introduces a large load time. When I open the new tab I get a lot of loading and a white screen until finally it loads up with the field selected. Any ideas on how I can get rid of this initial load state?

Comment: Nm it was my mistake. I copied the 'focus.html' to create a 'start-focused.html' which included the focus.js script. So it was bouncing around constantly with the location redirect.  So this seems to have worked! Thank you so much!